# Group by query not working fine According me

Tags: php, sql, group-by

I want to get a values group_by 'recivedID' but not working fine. find value only one first value is show on form how show all add all values and show.

**table 'fuel_transaction'**

```
recivedID hsdltrs
      1     500
      1     600
      1     300
      2     100
      2     600
```

result show on form // no need

```
recivedID ->1 
hsdltrs ->500  //worng result
```

I need result

```
//hsdltrs ->500+600+300=1400

    recivedID ->1 
    hsdltrs ->1400


 <?php
      //$this->db->Select SUM(ABS(hsdltrs)) as Data ; //error please check its sir                                
      $this->db->where('issuedate >=',$date1);
      $this->db->where('issuedate <=',$date2);
      $this->db->where('recivedID',$a); 
      $this->db->group_by('recivedID');
      $queryb = $this->db->get('fuel_transaction'); 
      if ($queryb->num_rows() > 0)
              {
                foreach ($queryb->result() as $rowc)
                    {
                    $tdate = $rowc->issuedate;
                    $hsdltrs = $rowc->hsdltrs;
                    $hsd += $rowc->hsdltrs;
                ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `select_sum`.
Then, inside your `foreach` it will be available using `$rowc->sumhsd`:

```php
$this->db->select_sum('hsdltrs', 'sumhsd'); //Here it comes                               
$this->db->where('issuedate >=',$date1);
$this->db->where('issuedate <=',$date2);
$this->db->where('recivedID',$a); 
$this->db->group_by('recivedID');
$queryb = $this->db->get('fuel_transaction'); 

if ($queryb->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($queryb->result() as $rowc) {
        $tdate = $rowc->issuedate;           
        $hsdltrs = $rowc->sumhsd; //Here you get the sum
```